# Overlay multiple images on a map in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a service that returns an array of images with 4 coordinates each (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right).

Is there a way to display these images over a map? This is my style function so far, but only the stroke is appearing:

```
function(feature) {
    var EO = feature.get('source');

    return [new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon({
            src: EO.image,
            rotateWithView: true,
        }),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#00F',
            width: 1
        })
    })]
}
```

Here is my dummy object array:

```
var dummy = [
    {
        coords: [
            [-9.223774, 38.755317],
            [-9.124210, 38.707109],
            [-9.158542, 38.664230],
            [-9.258964, 38.711396]
        ],
        image: 'dummy/eo/eo1.jpg'
    }
];
```

Here is the loop that turns my dummy into features:

```
dummy.forEach(function(EO) {
    var projectedCoords = EO.coords.map(function(coord) {
        return ol.proj.fromLonLat(coord, 'EPSG:3395');
    });

    var EOFeature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Polygon([projectedCoords]));

    EOFeature.set('source', {
        image: EO.image
    });

    EOFeature.set('type', 'EO');

    features.push(EOFeature);
});
```

Comment: Your function looks good since `EO.image` is a valid source. And maybe you show some more code.

Comment: `EO.image` is a valid source. The problem is that `style.Icons` only accept point geometries, and I wanted to pass in a polygon geometry. Also `Icons` are scale independent.

I updated the original question with some more code.

Comment: Do you want the image cover the whole polygon?

Comment: That would be the idea, yes.

Comment: I don't think this can be done, have you seen any example of that?

Comment: No, looked everywhere, asked @ #openlayers IRC channel, but no luck. Maybe if I could get a hold of an OL dev...